# using sum to custom function in laravel

Tags: laravel

i have custom function in my Model

```
public function bkd(){
        $sifat = 0;
        $sks = $this->sks;
        $bkd = 0;
        if($this->sifat == 'Team Teaching'){
            $sifat = 0.5;
            $bkd = $sifat * $sks;
            return $bkd;
        }elseif($this->sifat == 'Asistensi'){
            $sifat = 1;
            $bkd = $sifat * $sks;
            return $bkd;
        }
    }
```

and from that, it will called in the table on the view with foreach.

```
@foreach($profil->kelas as $kls)
          <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
          <td>{{ $kls->matakuliah->nama}}</th>
          <td>{{ $kls->grup}}</td>
          <td>{{ $kls->sifat}}</td>
          <td>{{ $kls->sks}}</td>
          <td>{{ $kls->semester}}</td>
          <td>{{ $kls->tahun_ajaran}}</td>
          <td>{{ $kls->bkd()}}</td>
          <td>
              <a href="/dosen/{{$profil->id}}/{{$kls->id}}/del_kelas" class="badge badge-danger" onclick="return confirm('Yakin Ingin Menghapus?')">DELETE</a>
          </td>
          </tr>
      @endforeach
```

I want to sum every record from the function bkd(), how can i do it?

this is what i try in the view

```
<li>Jumlah Beban Pengajaran di Sistem Informasi<span>{{$kelas->sum('bkd')}}</span></li>
```

but its give me error

> App\Kelas::bkd must return a relationship instance.

Comment: You can't do it like `->sum('bkd')`, since `bkd` is neither a property or a relationship method. You can loop and assign to a variable, like `$bkds = 0;`, then in the loop `$bkds += $kls->bkd();`, but yeah; `->sum()` doesn't work on that type of method.

Comment: An accessor would be better than that function, but you can still do the sum with the reduce method `$profil->kelas->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    return $carry + $item->bkd();
}, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you use accesor:

```
class YourModel
{
    protected $appends = ['bkd'];
    public function getBkdAttribute()
    {
      //stuff
    }
}
$kls->bkd; //value
$kelas->sum('bkd'); //sum of values
```